# Dynamic gridview - how to reference in rowdatabound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am dynamically creating several gridviews depending on data in a DB.
I generate the gridview as follows in a foreach statement:

```
GridView gdv = new GridView();
gdv.ID = "gdv" + i.ToString();
gdv.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(gdv_SelectedIndexChanged);
gdv.RowDataBound += gdv_RowDataBound;
```

RowDataBound looks like the following:

```
protected void gdv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {             
      e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(((GridView)sender), "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
   }
}
```

This all works as expected, however the ((GridView)sender) returns the following value:

```
&#39;gdv00&#39;
```

What i need returned for this link to work is the following:

```
&#39;ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$Main$gdv0&#39;
```

Pretty sure this has something to do with the master pages? but not sure how to reference this properly in the rowdatabound event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$Main$gdv is the UniqueID property of the grid control (client ID is separated by _).  This is the ID rendered to the browser.  I think the problem here is that the control isn't added to the control tree immediately, which has been a problem for some in the past.  Try doing it this way:

```
GridView gdv = new GridView();
gdv.ID = "gdv" + i.ToString();
panel.Controls.Add(gdv);

//set grid props
```

HTH.

Comment: Perfect! worked a treat, just changed the panel add before i bound the databind and it works now
Thanks.